# Multisampled Texture

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

i have some doubts with multisampled textures.

In fragment shader, how to pass multiple samples?

We use glTexImage2DMultisample instead of glTeximage2D. so, how to upload texture data?

I want to use default FBO for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly use a multisampled texture. You have to resolve it to another texture (same format, same size) first.

You can do that by binding the non-multisampled texture and blitting the multisampled one to it with [glBlitFramebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml) (you might need to append EXT to function name - use glBlitFramebufferEXT - if you use OpenGL 2).

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: @Roshan More details on what, exactly?

Comment: You mean render to texture? also, what will be the fragment shader for multisampled textures?

Comment: 1) Render to texture - what? Binding a buffer and changing some pixels via draw calls / blitting is "render to texture". Not sure how that changes anything, though. 2) There is no "fragment shader for multisampled textures". Drawing to a multisampled texture generally doesn't require shader changes. And it is not allowed to use a multisampled texture in draw calls.